# Python Reading from a file to create a weighted directed graph using networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx, spyder

I am new at python and Spyder.
I am trying to read from a text file with format into a graph using networkx:

```
FromNodeId  ToNodeId    Weight
0   1   0.15
0   2   0.95
0   3   0.8
0   4   0.5
0   5   0.45
0   6   0.35
0   7   0.4
0   8   0.6
0   9   0.45
0   10  0.7
1   2   0.45
1   11  0.7
1   12  0.6
1   13  0.75
1   14  0.55
1   15  0.1
...
```

I want to use Networkx graph format that can store such a large graph(about 10k nodes, 40k edges).

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.read_edgelist('test.txt', nodetype=int, create_using= nx.DiGraph())

print(nx.info(g))
nx.draw(g)
plt.show()
```

When I run this code, nothing happens.
I am using Spyder for editing.
Could you help? Thanks!

Comment: "nothing happens" like the print function doesn't even print? Perhaps there is an error in nx.read_edgelist(...) that doesn't show up. Try it in cmd line. Also if you copied and pasted your code, there is a wrong indentation and your "G" is not passed to the function, but "g".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have comment first line with symbol `#` (`read_edgelist` by default skip lines start with `#`):

```
#FromNodeId  ToNodeId    Weight
 0   1   0.15
 0   2   0.95
 0   3   0.8
```

Then modify call of `read_edgelist` to define type of weight column:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.read_edgelist('./test.txt', nodetype=int,
  data=(('weight',float),), create_using=nx.DiGraph())

print(g.edges(data=True))
nx.draw(g)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1, {'weight': 0.15}), (0, 2, {'weight': 0.95}), (0, 3, {'weight':
0.8}), (0, 4, {'weight': 0.5}), (0, 5, {'weight': 0.45}), (0, 6, {'weight': 0.35}), (0, 7, {'weight': 0.4}), (0, 8, {'weight': 0.6}), (0, 9, {'weight': 0.45}), (0, 10, {'weight': 0.7}), (1, 2, {'weight':
0.45}), (1, 11, {'weight': 0.7}), (1, 12, {'weight': 0.6}), (1, 13, {'weight': 0.75}), (1, 14, {'weight': 0.55}), (1, 15, {'weight':
0.1})]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why the syntax is data=(('weight',float),),? I mean adding a comma right after the inner parentheses. I did not see the explanation in the document file of the networkx. Maybe it is just the rule to write in this way?

Comment: To my best knowledge this solution is the only way to read and write directed graphs in networkx as adjacency lists (.adjlist) do not preserve edges directions. I'm using nx.write_edgelist(G, "test_graph.edgelist") to write a directed graph and read_edgelist as above to read it from disk.