# Multi Directed Graph in NetworkX not loading

Tags: python, networking, data-science, networkx

I am trying to load in a Multi Directed Graph in NetworkX for a programming assignment with a given txt file, but it is not working. There are no errors, but when I graph the graph and when I do a quick check check to see how many nodes/edges there are it returns 0 for both - which leads me to believe that it is just not loading in the file into the graph at all. Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
def answer_one():
    # Your Code Here
    G = nx.read_edgelist('email_network.txt', delimiter='\\t', data=[('time', int)], create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())
    return G
answer_one()
```

Here is a bit of the file I am trying to read in (email_network.txt):

```
#Sender Recipient   time
1   2   1262454010
1   3   1262454010
1   4   1262454010
1   5   1262454010
1   6   1262454010
1   7   1262454010
1   8   1262454010
1   9   1262454010
1   10  1262454010
1   11  1262454010
1   12  1262454010
1   13  1262454010
1   14  1262454010
1   15  1262454010
```

I looked at [Python Reading from a file to create a weighted directed graph using networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292159/python-reading-from-a-file-to-create-a-weighted-directed-graph-using-networkx) and https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html?highlight=read_edgelist to try to find what parameters I am using wrong but neither of them were that helpful.

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong/how to load in the file correctly? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found it, it was
`G = nx.read_edgelist('email_network.txt', edgetype=int, data=(('weight', int),), create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())`